# Cannot find why tables cannot be renamed

Tags: django

What could be the cause of that issue:

```
Applying django_orm.0002_rename_tables_...Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "."
"fergo"."tb_kel" RENAME TO "fergo"."tb_kelo"
"fergo"."tb_sa" RENAME TO "fergo"."tb_sartop"
```

There is for sure not a typo or syntax error or something. This error appears for all tables which to be renamed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please also provide your source python code/line that cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this:

```
alter table public.shoes rename to public.shoe_test;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: alter table public.shoes rename to public.shoe_test;

alter table public.shoes rename to shoe_test;
ALTER TABLE
```

You can't schema qualify the new name.

If you where wanting to change schema then you would need to use:

```
ALTER TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] name
    SET SCHEMA new_schema
```